# Drawrect memory leak

Tags: ios, memory, drawrect

I am subclassing an `UIView` in order to draw custom figures on a view, the view itself will be quite large, could go up to 10000 x 10000, we are using this large view so we can accommodate high level of zooms. I have tried various things to draw on a view, either by overwriting `drawRect:` or by adding a sublayer. However with sublayers on zoom or scroll motion becomes jerky and has a visible lag. This is due to sublayer being redrawn a lot.

With `drawRect:` however things are quite smooth except when I overwrite `drawRect:` there are a lot of memory usage, for 2000 x 2000 sized view it takes 70.5 mb (I am calling `[super drawRect:rect]` with no benefit). If I do not overwrite drawrect I can set my custom view to any size I tried even 30000 x 30000, there was no problem in regards to memory. However as soon as `drawRect:` gets overwrite memory leaks occur. My project is ARC based, I am quite satisfied with performance when using `drawRect:` to draw custom shapes, so I was wondering if there is a way to plug the memory leak? or optimize it a bit.

Any help is much appreciated, please let me know if I have not clarified something

Regards

The main/default viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "P10Maps.h"

@interface P10ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

}
@end
```

The main/default viewcontroller.m

```
#import "P10ViewController.h"
@interface P10ViewController ()

@end

@implementation P10ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[self initializeViews];
    //[self coordinateGen];
    mapView = [[P10Maps alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2000, 2000)];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000,2000);
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = -10;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:0.2 animated:YES];
    scrollView.delegate = (id)self;

    }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return mapView;
}
@end
```

The subclass for UIview .h and .m respectively

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "P10ViewController.h"
@interface P10Maps : UIView

@end

#import "P10Maps.h"

@implementation P10Maps
int countryID;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
    [self drawPaths];
    if (self) {
        //self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

Comment: Because you might be correct, but there may also be some other stuff going on there.  It's also good practice for askers to post their code.  Not every solution is going to be as 'obvious'.

Comment: For 2kx2k the backing store might be expected to be 16MB, not 70.5MB so there may be another problem. Perhaps some autorelease pools might be needed. For 10k x 10k some kind of tile-ing is probably going to be needed.

Comment: I have updated with the code, any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you overwrite drawRect if you only call super inside it??? What do you want to do with drawRect??
As the comments say: `// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.`

Comment: I actually have drawn bezier paths inside drawrect, but drawing them does not effect memory consumption (thats why I have not included that in the code), as soon as I overwrite drawrect for any purpose memory leak starts to occur. Regarding [super drawrect] I read on documentation (If I have not misunderstood) that calling it will plug memory issues among others.

Comment: By leaving out code including drawPaths you are not helping anyone help you. It's too vague. You should use Instruments to find leaks or memory pressure points in your code paths.